# Rails allow :new, :show, but not :edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a trivia app where each user can answer a daily trivia question exactly one time.  I can see using the `:new` action to answer the question and the `:show` action to show how the user answered, but I want the URLs to be the same.

So I want the same URL (http://example.com/daily_question) to render either `:new` if the user is just arriving for the first time today or `:show` if the user has already answered the daily question.  What's the easiest way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the show and new action cannot give the same url, because show expects an 'id' to be in the url and new action expect the word 'new' at the end of the url.
If you need the same url, do not force it on the show or new action. Just create your own custom method in the controller then, and match it in the routes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with HTTP verbs and actions 
your show action show have find or build of the question ie

```
def show
  @question = current_user.daily_question || current_user.build_daily_question
end
```

and than just use update attirbutes in your edit action 
so you have

```
GET /show
PUT /edit
```